# Can we add support for React 16.8 (or latest) in Stack Snippets?

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

Currently [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/stack-snippets/info) supports up to 16.6.3. It will be great to add the support for 16.8 as this is a major release because of [React hooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework)#React_hooks) support.

Now the alternative is each time manually add the [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) links in HTML code snippet with the latest React versions.

Comment: It would also be nice if the version/configuration of babel were updated so that it would not error on [dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports) or on async/await. All modern browsers support these anyway, the only reason to turn Babel on at all is to get jsx support.